# How to display the value of hidden when checkbox is checked in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

Im having problem on how to get the value of the hidden input box once the checkbox is checked. here are my code.

```
<label class="control control--checkbox"><span>Additional</span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="apply[]" value=""/>
   <input type="hidden" name="option[]" value="1 bottle"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="cost[]" value="$20"/>
</label>
<label class="control control--checkbox"><span>Additional</span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="apply[]" value=""/>
   <input type="hidden" name="option[]" value="3 bottle"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="cost[]" value="$50"/>
</label>
```

My Php code:

```
<?php 
$options = $_POST['option'];
$costs = $_POST['cost']; 
$apply = $_POST['apply'];
if (isset($apply)) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$option.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

It seems that the option of my php code is always two, i want only to display that was checked and dont display that are not.

can someone advise me on how can i solve this problem or any work around to get the same result?

Comment: You need to use `jQuery` to do this OR if your checkbox checked depending on the PHP value then you can use the condition for the display of hidden inputs.

Comment: i see. do you have any idea on how can i do this in jquery? i havent tried in jquery. i want to solve the problem in php first but if there is no other way then i will try your jquery if you have any.

Comment: how are you differentiating the two input boxes? By the option? Why are the names arrays? If you are assigning one value to it, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Check the example: https://jsfiddle.net/wkLx7d6o/

Comment: @FrayneKonok The Fiddle is broke, when you attempt to click both of them, it is possible. The OP would just need to add some possible checking for that and uncheck in jQuery.

Comment: @McStuffins, I make this example depending on the OP's demand __how to get the value of the hidden input box once the checkbox is checked__ only.

Comment: @FrayneKonok true, I just came up with some php way to do  this. I have no way of testing this though.

Comment: How many check boxes would be checked? Only one or more?

Comment: Watch Out my first comment, I give two choice to the OP and he want to check the jQuery once for the testing purpose but he need this with PHP.

Comment: @McStuffins, The example shows the value of hidden options for only the checkbox is checked at a time and the closest value from it.

Comment: @McStuffins actually, those two boxes are like group of each checkbox. if the checkbox 1 is checked it will get all the hidden value of that checkbox. that is what im planning. boxes to be checked will be one or more or possible the user will not check the checkbox.

Comment: @Joffrey, That is what exactly my example do for only options, you may try it with another value.

Comment: thanks. im currently testing it now.

Comment: this english is very hard for me to understand, but I think I understand what you are trying to say. Is it that you want both of them to be checked, or do you just want a single one? Like a radio button? If the values will be different, then why don't you name them differently also?

Comment: @McStuffins sorry for my bad english. I want both of them to be checked but each one of the have different hidden value that i want to display.

Comment: @Joffrey Why don't you give them separate names which could then be used by php to get the value. Possibly add another hidden value for the name. You could do a switch in PHP, but maybe it is easier to do in jQuery. I don't know the answer in jQuery though.

Comment: @McStuffins, The name is different, Did you notice the `[]` after the name which differ the values from each other in PHP.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I did, but in php, that would just increment the array value. I don't know if it is the same in HTML.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I tried using your example and its working. Is there a way that I can solve this without using jquery, just purely php?

Comment: How?? I don't think, Cause this is a run time entity and if you know the value and want that if the checkbox is checked than there is a solution, in your state you need jQuery.

Comment: @Joffrey This is what I am trying to explain. If you could provide me with a `var_dump($_POST);` I would appreciate it and i'll then be able to give you an example. Are you trying to do this real time, or do you want to update something live? You could possibly use an AJAX call. Inevitably ending up writing something in jQuery to change the values of a <div>

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will get the var_dump of this. Currently doing local and I will update this to a live website

Comment: this is the var_dump(). hope it helps. array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" } array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "$20" [1]=> string(3) "$50" } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "1 bottle" [1]=> string(8) "3 bottle" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP you need to set the CheckBox value and then are able to find the other values.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="apply[]" value="y"/>
```

**PHP**

```
$options = $_POST['option'];
$costs = $_POST['cost']; 
$apply = $_POST['apply'];
if(isset($apply)) {
    foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
        if($option == 'y'){
            echo $costs[$key];
            echo $apply[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

Using jQuery you can get the Hidden values like-

```
$(function(){
    $('.input_check').on("change", function(){
    var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(chk == true){
        var val = $(this).closest('label').find('.option').val();
        console.log(val);
    }
  })
})
```